# Typescript Record inside Record

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a reducer that I'm having trouble trying to type.
In some of my functions I use a string name to look up the state.
Example:

```
// name been the name of the key
const { value } = state[name]
```

The issue I'm having is extends Record and finding out the any part.
I tried using `Record<string, Record<string, string | boolean>>` but that causes a problem if you try to do something like

```
const {value } = state[name]
value.slice(....
```

The above value could be a boolean based on my typing which would cause slice to error as boolean can not have a slice method.

Question is what should be the typing for this

```
 interface IState extends Record<string, Record<string, any>> {
```

Full example of code below:

```
interface IAction {
  type: string
  payload: Payload
}

type Payload = {
  value?: string
  show?: boolean
}

interface IState extends Record<string, Record<string, any>> {
  fieldA: Payload
  fieldB: Payload
}

const initialState = {
  filedA: { value: '', show: false },
  filedB: { value: '', show: false },
}

const reducer = (state: IState, action: IAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'fieldA': {
      return {
        ...state,
        fieldA: { ...state.fieldA, ...action.payload },
      }
    }
    case 'fieldB': {
      return {
        ...state,
        fieldB: { ...state.fieldB, ...action.payload },
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Then use a regular object type; `interface IState extends Record<string, { value: string; show: boolean }> {`? I don't know what's the problem here...

Comment: *"In some of my functions I use a string name to look up the state."* - Why not show these? They seem to be the issue. The code in the question seems to work just fine, allthough  it is not clear why you need to extend `Record` in the first place.

Comment: @Tobias S. If I was to not use a Record then I get the warning ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IState'.``` when calling const {value } = state[name].

Comment: @caTS I tried using the object but got the following warning. ```Property 'fieldA' of type 'Payload' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ value: string; show: boolean; }'.```

Comment: @caTS is correct. You're likely getting that `Property 'fieldA' of type 'Payload' is not assignable to 'string' index type` message because you're trying to stuff `fieldA` one level too deep somewhere, trying to store it inside of `value` instead of inside of the higher level object.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your issue has to do with index signatures:

> I have a reducer that I'm having trouble trying to type. In some of my functions I use a string name to look up the state. Example:
>
> ```
> // name been the name of the key
> const { value } = state[name]
> ```

Your `Record` type is saying the reducer can have any `string` as a property key -- can it?

##### With Known Properties

If your state has a limited number of known keys, like the `'fieldA'` and `'fieldB'` in your example, then in my opinion you are going about it backwards by trying to force a broader type on the state.  A better solution would be to refine the type of the `name` variable such that you know that it is a valid property key and not just any `string`.

These types work with your current reducer:

```
type Payload = {
  value?: string
  show?: boolean
}

interface IState {
  fieldA: Payload
  fieldB: Payload
}

export type StateKey = keyof IState

interface IAction {
  type: StateKey
  payload: Payload
}
```

And will work in a selector, so long as we enforce that `name` is a valid key:

```
const someSelector = (state: IState, name: StateKey): string | undefined => {
  const { value } = state[name];
  // Note: value is possibly undefined
  return value?.slice(0, 4);
}
```

##### With any `string` Property

On the other hand, if your `state` really can have any `string` as a property, then you can use a `Record`.  It is not a nested `Record` because the second-level properties are known.

The state type would be:

```
type IState = Record<string, Payload>;
```